# Triangle and parallel lines, find angle x

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image]

I need to find the minimum angle value of $x$, where $\cal L_1$ and $\cal L_2$ are parallel lines and the angle $\angle ABC$ is acute.
I can´t figure out how to relate the angles. So far I only know the adiacent ones as $180°-2\theta-3\beta$ and $180°-3\theta-2\beta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice first of all that $x=\pi-3(\beta+\theta)$. By angle chasing it is easy to find that $\angle ABC=5(\beta+\theta)-\pi$. But you know that $\angle ABC<\pi/2$, whence $\beta+\theta<3\pi/10$ and $x>\pi/10$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aretino. How did you find out that ∠ABC=5(β+θ)−π ?

Comment: Extend the line going from point $A$ to $\cal L_1$, to meet $\cal L_2$ at $C$. You can find easily the angles at $A$ and $C$ in triangle $ABC$.